# Update multiple rows in the index view Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, edit, crud

I am a beginner in laravel and I am trying to update all the records in the index view without having to enter to a different view to edit each item.

The idea is to click a button, and when I click on it the input data is enable to change the quantity of all data that is show in the index; and then have a submit button to update all the records.

At the moment when I click on the button it only enable the inputs of the first row, how can i do to enable all of them?

And how can I make a function in the controller to update all the records in my datatable at once, only clicking on a submit button??

I dont really know how to edit nd update the data in the same index page!!! 
PLEASE HELP ME.

[This is the default index view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfRaD.jpg)
[This is what happens when i click the "Editar cantidades" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yWYP.jpg)

**View**

```
@extends ('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')

<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4>
        <a href="consumibles/create" class="pull-right btn btn-primary">Crear nuevo consumible</a>
        Listado de consumibles
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
        @include('inventlab.consumibles.search')
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a id="enablebutton" class="pull-right btn btn-default" >Editar cantidades</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-hover nowrap" id="example" width="100%">
        <thead class="thead-default">
            <tr>
                <th>Opciones</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th style="text-align: center">Sin abrir</th>
                <th style="text-align: center">En uso</th>
                <th style="text-align: center">Cantidad total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach ($consumibles as $cons)
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{URL::action('ConsumibleController@edit',$cons->id_cons)}}" class="link-underlined margin-right-5"><i class="icmn-pencil5"> </i> </a>
                    <a href="" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$cons->id_cons}}" data-toggle="modal" class="link-underlined"><i class="icmn-bin"> </i> </a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ $cons->nom_cons }}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">

                    <input type='number' name='cant_sinabrir' id="sinabrir" value='{{ $cons->cant_sinabrir }}' disabled style="text-align: center;width: 3em;" min="0" />

                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <input type='number' name='cant_enuso' id="enuso" value='{{ $cons->cant_enuso }}' disabled style="text-align: center;width: 3em;" min="0" />
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <input type='number' name='cant_total' id='total' value='{{ $cons->cant_total }}' disabled disabled style="text-align: center;width: 3em;" min="0" />
                </td>

            </tr>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#enablebutton').click(function(){
                        $('#sinabrir').removeAttr('disabled').focus();
                        $('#enuso').removeAttr('disabled').focus();
                    });
                });
            </script>
            @include('inventlab.consumibles.modal')
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Controller**
My index controller is ok, but I don't know how to make the **update function** run through all the records in the database and save the new values.

```
public function index(Request $request)
  {
    if ($request){
      $query=trim($request->get('searchText'));
      $consumibles=DB::table('consumibles')
      ->where('nom_cons','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
      ->orwhere('alerta','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
      ->orderBy('nom_cons','asc')
      ->get();
      return view('inventlab.consumibles.index',["consumibles"=>$consumibles,"searchText"=>$query]);
    }
  }//End function index  


public function update(ConsumibleFormRequest $request)
  {

    $data = $request->all();
    $validate = $this->validateRegister($data);
    if($validate['code'] == 200)
    {
      $register = $validate['data'];
      $holder = Consumible::find($id);
      $holder->update($register);
      return Redirect::to('inventlab/consumibles');
    }
    else
    {
      return("No se pudo actualizar el registro");
    }
    return "Registro actualizado"; 
  }//End function update
```

My current update function works when I have a different view and edit one per one record.

Comment: Why you dont use ajax?

Comment: I suggest you doing that using bootstrap. It has nothing to do with Laravel. somwthing like this: `<p data-edit v-html="currentClient.paypal_email ? currentClient.paypal_email : 'N/A'"></p>
                        <input class="form-control d-none" data-edit type="email"/>` notice the `data-edit` and search for it in bootstrap. I am just giving you the keywords and I have used that before.